# re.match versus re.findall

Tags: python, regex

Why is it, `re.match` returns the `None` object whilst a similar `re.findall` returns a non-empty result?

I'm parsing email subjects. The one in question is

```
subject = "=?UTF-8?B?0JLQsNGI0LUg0YHQvtC+0LHRidC10L3QuNC1INC90LUg0LTQvtGB0YLQsNCy0LvQtdC90L4=?=. Mail failure."
```

I'm wondering why

`re.match("mail failure", subject, re.I)` returns the None object whist the counterpart

`re.findall("mail failure", subject, re.I)` returns the matched string in a list `['Mail failure']`

What is wrong in my thoughts?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) matches the pattern from the start of the string.  [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) however *searches* for occurrences of the pattern anywhere in the string.

If you have the pattern `"mail failure"` and the string:

```
subject = "=?UTF-8?B?0JLQsNGI0LUg0YHQvtC+0LHRidC10L3QuNC1INC90LUg0LTQvtGB0YLQsNCy0LvQtdC90L4=?=. Mail failure."
```

`re.match` will return `None` because the string does not start with `"mail failure"`.  `re.findall` though will return a match because the string contains `"mail failure"`.

Comment: I always thought "^mail failure" would match exactly from the start and "mail failure" anywhere in the string. Ok, so the correct pattern for `re.match` would be `".*mail failure"`?

Comment: @Al_ - Yes, that pattern will return a match object.

Comment: @Al_ - Also, just for reference, the pattern `"^mail failure"` tells Python to match `mail failure` at the start of the string, not anywhere in it.  `^` when used like that means "at the start".

Comment: I see. From the definition of `re.match`, `re.match("mail failure")` is similar to `re.match("^mail failure")`. However, `re.search("mail failure")` is obviously different from `re.search("^mail failure")`. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: So I didn't read this and spent 1 hour to discover that by definition `match` doesn't support *lookbehind*

Answer (score 9):

It's right here in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html
What you want is `re.search`.

> Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.